# DataStore thread execution

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-jetpack-datastore

I am curious about on which thread does the SharedPreferences substitute - Preferences DataStore operate - read and write data.

I searched for information but couldn't find any, only one article - this one https://medium.com/@vgoyal_1/datastore-android-how-to-use-it-like-a-pro-using-kotlin-2c2440683d78 and it is the first place where I see it is mentioned on which thread are the operations executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the DataStore code labs states - Dispatchers.IO - https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-proto-datastore#3

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35073540)